# Replace content between two lines in a PHP file

Tags: php

I have a PHP file, and I am writing a script at the moment which needs to replace a function with another one. The best way I thought of doing this would be to look between the two line numbers (which will always be the same), 126 and 136, and then replace between those two lines.

What I cannot do is include any of the original function in the modifier script so I cannot just look through the file for the function name etc (I am create a script to modify another paid script that I don't own the copyright to so I cannot include any of it).

The function that I need to replace is

```
function upload_supports_preview($upload) {

  if($upload->thumbnail != 'none') {

    return true;

  }

  return false;

}
```

and I have to replace it with

```
function upload_supports_preview($upload) {

  if($upload->type == 'video' || $upload->type == 'audio' || $upload->type == 'image') {

    return true;

  }

  return false;

}
```

Comment: "another payed script"... most likely you mean copyright protected code? Whether you payed for it or not does not change a thing, does it? And _if_ it is copyright protected, are you sure you are granted the right to alter that code?

Comment: Why do you need a script for that? If you have that code in multiple files, you are apparently duplicating code through copy and pasting. Fix the duplication instead.

Comment: There is a script available online through CodeCanyon, and what I am doing is writing a separate script that modified the CodeCanyon script to add additional features. I have permission from the author of the script, provided that I do not include any of his script in my package.

Comment: Ok, but why do you need to change it programmatically then? Why can't you just change the lines? And also, if you change ten lines and include the rest, wouldn't that still be pretty much including his script?

Comment: Users buy his script, and then I offer another script that users can upload to their server that modifies his script. Sort of like a Wordpress plugin. I do not include any of his script in mine.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like a very good idea to me, and this isn't a very nice solution but it should work.

```
$filename = '/home/xyz.php';

// this loads the file into an array
$lines = file($filename);

// edit each line of code
$lines[126] = '// put some code here';
$lines[127] = '// put some code here';
$lines[128] = '// put some code here';
$lines[129] = '// put some code here';
$lines[130] = '// put some code here';
$lines[131] = '// put some code here';
$lines[132] = '// put some code here';
$lines[133] = '// put some code here';
$lines[134] = '// put some code here';
$lines[135] = '// put some code here';
$lines[136] = '// put some code here';

// write the file back to disk
// this joins the array back into a string, using the current end of line marker from your system, which could be different to what the source file used, but will still work
file_put_contents($filename, join(PHP_EOL, $lines));
```

Answer (score 0):

`runkit` allows you to undefine a function at runtime, then you can redefine it the way you want to. This means you don't have to alter the script, but can inject the code you want. Check the copyright though, most likely you violate it, if the script is published under a commercial license.

Comment: to make this answer (more) useful, you could link to the corresponding manual page and the appropriate function from runkit. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question

Comment: putting the link would have taken you the same time it took to write that comment